# Return result from google analytics callback

Tags: google-analytics, coffeescript

I'm trying to return the clientId from google analytics. The proper way to get the clientId is through the following.

```
ga(tracker)->
  clientId = tracker.get('clientId')
```

But I would like to encapsulate so I can get the result with a function. I've been trying to do something like this. It still returns undefined. I would be grateful if I could get some help how to achieve it.

```
getClientId = (callback) ->
  ga(tracker)->
    clientId = tracker.get('clientId')
    if clientId
      return callback("&gaId=" + clientId)
    else
      return callback('')
    )

getString = (string) -> return string

result = getClientId(getString)
```

Comment: There isn't enough code to understand your question.  what do you mean by client id?   how are you trying to get it?

Comment: The instructions that google provide is to get `clientId` is the following: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie

Does that make it clearer? The ClientId is an identifier that you can get from google analytics that way.

Comment: I stand corrected it used to be referred to as cid.

Comment: @DaImTo, so do you have a solution or some guidance?